# What are the boundary value conditions for generic HJBs in economics?

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, optimal-control, continuous-time, bellman-equations

Consider a routine continuous time optimization problem:
$
V(t,a_{t}) := 
\max \int_{\tau=t}^{\tau = T} 
e^{-\rho (\tau -t)} u(c_{\tau})d\tau
$ $\text{  s.t. }$
$\dot{a}_{t} = y + ra_{t} - c_{t}$,
$a_{0} \text{ given, } a_{T}=0.$
Assume y & r are constants and $u(c)=\frac{c^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}$.

**Optimal control approach**:
$H := u(c_{t}) + \lambda (y + ra_{t} - c_{t})$
Boils down to a BVP (two ODEs w/ unkown $c_{t}, a_{t}$):
$\left[\begin{array}{l}
\dot{c}=\left(\frac{r-\rho}{\gamma} \right) c
\\
\dot{a}_{t} = y + ra_{t} - c_{t}
\\
a(0)=a_0
\\ 
a_{T}=0
\end{array} \right]$.
This can be plugged into a [DiffEq](https://github.com/SciML/DifferentialEquations.jl) solver bc we have two first-order ODEs w/ two boundary conditions.

**HJB approach**:
$\rho V(t,a_{t}) = \max_{c} \left\{u(c_{t}) + V_{a}(t,a_{t})\times \left(y + ra_{t} - c_{t} \right) + V_{t}(t,a_{t}) \right\}$
FOC: $c(t,a_{t})=u'^{-1}(V_{a}(t,a_{t})) = (V_{a}(t,a_{t}))^{-\frac{1}{\gamma}}$
This boils down to a PDE w/ unknown function $V(t,a_{t})$:
$\left[\begin{array}{l}
\rho V(t,a_{t}) = u(c_{t}) + V_{a}(t,a_{t})\times \left(y + ra_{t} - c_{t} \right) + V_{t}(t,a_{t}) 
\\
c(t,a_{t}) = (V_{a}(t,a_{t}))^{-\frac{1}{\gamma}}
\end{array} \right]$
To solve this first-order PDE we need one boundary condition for $V(t,a_{t})$.
**Issue**: we have boundary conditions for $a_{t}$ $(a(0)=a_0, a_{T}=0)$ but not for $V(t,a_{t})$.
**Question**: How do we get the boundary conditions for HJBs in general?

**Partial answer** (case 1): finite-horizon deterministic problems
$V(T,a_{T}) = \psi(a_{T}) = 0$   (no bequest here by assumption)
$\left[\begin{array}{l}
\rho V(t,a_{t}) = u(c_{t}) + V_{a}(t,a_{t})\times \left(y + ra_{t} - c_{t} \right) + V_{t}(t,a_{t}) 
\\
c(t,a_{t}) = (V_{a}(t,a_{t}))^{-\frac{1}{\gamma}}
\\
V(T,a) = 0 \text{ , } \forall a
\end{array} \right]$

Generically, many problems in economics can be written:
$V(t,x_{t}) := 
\max \int_{\tau=t}^{\tau = T} e^{-\rho (\tau -t)}u(\tau,x_{\tau},c_{\tau})d\tau +
\Omega(T,x_{T})$  $\text{  s.t. }$
$\dot{x}_{t} = g(t,x_{t},c_{t})$,
$x_{0} \text{ given, } x_{T}=0.$

The generic optimal control problem is straightforward, w/ boundary conditions $x_{0}, x_{T}=0$.

Generic deterministic HJB:
$\left[\begin{array}{l}
\rho V(t,x_{t}) = \max_{c} \left\{u(t,x_{t},c_{t}) 
+ V_{x}(t,x_{t}) \dot{x} + V_{t}(t,x_{t}) \right\} 
\\
V(T,x_{T}) = \Omega(T,x)  \text{ , } \forall x
\end{array} \right]$

**Case 2**: finite horizon stochastic problems (w/ Ito processes)
$V(t,x_{t}) := 
\max \int_{\tau=t}^{\tau = T} e^{-\rho (\tau -t)} u(\tau,x_{\tau},c_{\tau})d\tau + \Omega(T,x_{T})$  $\text{  s.t. }$
$dx=\mu_{t}dt + \sigma_{t} dz_{t}$, where $\mu_{t} = g(t,x_{t},c_{t})$,
$x_{0} \text{ given, } x_{T}=0.$
$\rho V(t,x_{t}) 
= 
\max_{c} \left\{ u(t,x_{t},c_{t}) 
+ E_{t}\frac{dV}{dt}\right\} 
$.
Ito's Lemma: if $X \sim dX=\mu_{t}dt + \sigma_{t} dZ_{t}$ $\Rightarrow$
$E_{t}\frac{dV(t,x_{t})}{dt} =
V_{t}(t,x_{t})  + \mu_{t}V_{x}(t,x_{t}) 
+ \frac{\sigma_{t}^2}{2} V_{xx}(t,x_{t})
$
$\left[\begin{array}{l}
\rho V(t,x_{t}) = 
\max_{c} \left\{ u(t, x_{t},c_{t}) 
+ V_{t}(t,x_{t})  + \mu_{t}V_{x}(t,x_{t}) 
+ \frac{\sigma_{t}^2}{2} V_{xx}(t,x_{t})
\right\} 
\\
V(T,x_{T}) = \Omega(T,x)   \text{ , } \forall x
\end{array} \right]$
**Question 2**: a generic HJB for a stochastic problem (w/ Ito risk) is a second-order PDE and we need two boundary conditions.
What is the second boundary condition for $V(t,x_{t})$?
My guess:
$\left[\begin{array}{l}
\rho V(t,x_{t}) = 
\max_{c} \left\{ u(x_{t},c_{t},t) 
+ V_{t}(t,x_{t})  + \mu_{t}V_{x}(t,x_{t}) 
+ \frac{\sigma_{t}^2}{2} V_{xx}(t,x_{t})
\right\} 
\\
V(T,x_{T}) = \Omega(T,x)    \text{ , } \forall x
\\
V_{x}(T,x_{T}) = \Omega_{x}(T,x)    \text{ , } \forall x
\end{array} \right]$

The two boundary conditions for the finite-horizon pdes above are usually called:
Value matching: $V(T,x_{T}) = \Omega(T,x_{T}) $
Smooth pasting: $V_{x}(T,x_{T}) = \Omega_{x}(T,x_{T}) $
In the original example $\Omega(T,x_{T}) =0$.

Remaining questions: what are the value matching & smooth pasting conditions for generic infinite horizon problems?
I've seen:
$\lim_{t \to \infty} E[ e^{-\rho t} V(x_{t}) ]=0$
$\lim_{t \to \infty} E[ e^{-\rho t} V_{x}(x_{t}) ]=0$

**Case 3**:
What is the boundary condition for an infinite horizon deterministic HJB?

**Case 4**:
What is the boundary condition for an infinite horizon stochastic HJB?

**Case 5**:
Problems with borrowing constraints etc studied by Moll and Gomez et al?

**Lesson 1**: PDEs are ALOT more [complicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663640/why-cant-we-say-that-all-pdes-of-a-specified-order-require-a-fixed-number-of-bo?rq=1) than ODEs.
An nth order ODE needs n boundary conditions.
An nth order hyperbolic PDE (wave eqn) needs n boundary conditions.
An nth order elliptic equation needs n/2 boundary conditions.
Is there a general rule for the HJB PDEs economists usually solve?

**Lesson 2**: HJB PDEs are usually solved w/ viscosity methods.

See Moll, [Lifecycle (finite horizon)](https://benjaminmoll.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/lifecycle.pdf).
See Moll, [Lecture 3, Slide 11](https://benjaminmoll.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lecture3_2149.pdf).
[Achdou, Han, Lasry, Lions, Moll (2020)](https://benjaminmoll.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/HACT.pdf) is the most seminal paper in this literature, but doesn't really answer this question.
This is challenging b/c it's hard to plug a pde into a pde-solver w/o the proper boundary conditions.

Comment: The terminology "value matching" and "smoothing pasting" are not being used correctly here. They occur in *free boundary* problems---e.g. exercise of American options or real options. There is no "boundary condition" at infinity for HJB equations. Rather HJB conditions are only necessary. Sufficiency is given by transversality-type conditions at infinity. In stochastic control, such sufficiency results are called *verification theorems*. One needs to first solve the HJB, then apply verification (second step commonly not done in economics).

Comment: Whatever the terminology, those conditions give the correct solution in the first two cases. 
See Laibson's [lecture notes](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/econ2010c/files/lectures_9-10_2010c_2014.pdf).

Comment: Evidently you're misreading the terminology from the linked notes.